# Clear input field using jasny inputmask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I use jasny bootstrap with inputmask to validate input.

http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/

Having the following code.

```
<input id="foo" type="text" class="form-control" data-mask="999-99-999-9999-9" placeholder="ISBN">
```

How can I clear the value of the input field? I have tried the following:

```
$("#foo").val('');
```

It doesn't clear the value. The previously entered value is still there. It feels like the jasny inputmask object has some state, which I'm unsure how to reset.

Comment: It works [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VA3wz/)

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVrNc/ .
Have you included jQuery properly? Did you use $(document).ready()?

Comment: Batu Zet: Seems I was using an old version of jasny. In your example, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

All u need to do is use html code

```
<input id="foo" type="text" class="form-control" data-mask="999-99-999-9999-9" placeholder="ISBN">
<input type="button" id="clear" value="clear">
```

and the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clear").click(function(){
   $("#foo").val("");
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I think I was not clear: I use jasny inputmask. I added a link in my question.

Comment: u can do it without jasny inputmask :D 
why it need to use jasny inputmask?